# extract text from dojo xhrPost

Tags: dojo, xmlhttprequest

I have a function in which I am doing a `dojo.xhrPost()`. Now the returning data is wrapped in an unwanted `<div>` which is framework specific and cannot be removed. How can I strip away the div element. Here is my code.

```
function sendForm() {
    var resultNode = dojo.create("li");
    dojo.xhrPost({
        url: "${sectionaddurl}",
        form: dojo.byId("sectionform"),
        load: function(newContent) {
            dojo.style(resultNode,"display","block");
            resultNode.innerHTML = newContent;                   
        },
        error: function() {
            resultNode.innerHTML = "Your form could not be sent.";
        }
    });           
    $("#sectionform")[0].reset();
    dojo.place(resultNode, "existing_coursesection", "first");
}
```

In jquery we would do `$("#some_ID").text();` where the id will be the div obtained via ajax.
Will dojo allow me to manipulate the request data which is like `<div id="unwanted_div">containing my text</div>`

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure these are the "best" ways to go at it but they shoud work

---

1) Have the data be interpreted as XML instead of plain text:

```
dojo.require('dojox.xml.parser');

dojo.xhrPost({
    //...
    handleAs: 'xml',
    //...
    load: function(response_div){
        //content should be xml now
        result.innerHTML = dojox.xml.parser.textContent(response_div);
    }
    //...
})
```

---

2) Convert it to html and then process it

```
//create a thworwaway div with the respnse
var d = dojo.create('div', {innerHTML: response});
result.innerHTML = d.firstChild.innerHTML;
```

2.1) Use dojo.query instead of .firstChild if you need smore sofistication.

Comment: I decided to use a JSP page insted of a JSPX page for my ajax pages, this way there is no un-wanted div

Answer (score 0):

I prefer handle as JSON format :) , dojo have more utilities to access and to iterate the response.

```
 dojo.xhrGet({
        url : url,
        handleAs : "json",
        failOk : true, //Indicates whether a request should be allowed to fail
        //(and therefore no console error message in the event of a failure)
        timeout : 20000,
        content: {//params},
        load: function(){ // something },
        preventCache: true,
        error: function(error, ioargs) {
            console.info("error function", ioargs);
            var message = "";
            console.info(ioargs.xhr.status, error);
            //error process
          },
        handle: function(response, ioargs) {
            var message = "";
            console.info(ioargs.xhr.status, error);
            switch (ioargs.xhr.status) {
            case 200:
                message = "Good request.";
                break;
            case 404:
                message = "The page you requested was not found.";
                break;
            case 0:
                message = "A network error occurred. Check that you are connected to the internet.";
                break;
            default:
                message = "An unknown error occurred";
            }
          }
      });
```